# SQL Server 2008 MERGE Instruction in another MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I'd like to create a stored procedure with two MERGE instructions.

The previous procedure was too slow (standard UPSERT):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM F_Fond with (updlock,serializable) WHERE F_ISIN = @ISIN)
    BEGIN 
    (...)
    END
(...)
```

So I tried to modify it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPrixNew]
    (@Table InsertPrixFond READONLY)
AS
    MERGE INTO F_Fond T
    USING @Table S ON T.F_ISIN = S.ISIN

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        BEGIN -- Here is the syntax problem...
            MERGE INTO F_PRIX P
            USING @Table S ON P.F_ISIN = S.ISIN
                           AND P.P_DATE = S.DATE

            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE F_PRIX 
                SET P_PRIX = S.PRIX 
                WHERE F_ISIN = S.ISIN AND P_DATE = S.DATE

            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT INTO F_PRIX (F_ISIN, P_DATE, P_PRIX) 
                VALUES (S.ISIN, S.DATE, S.PRIX);             
        END

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO F_FOND (F_ISIN, F_DATE_PRIX, F_Prix_Jour) 
          VALUES (S.ISIN, S.DATE, S.PRIX)

          INSERT INTO F_PRIX (F_ISIN, P_DATE, P_PRIX) 
          VALUES (S.ISIN, S.DATE, S.PRIX)     
      END;
-- Let's update F_DATE_PRIX
 UPDATE F_FOND SET F_DATE_PRIX = @Table.DATE, F_Prix_Jour = @Table.PRIX 
  INNER JOIN @Table ON @Table.ISIN = F_Fond.F_ISIN 
  WHERE @Table.DATE >= F_DATE_PRIX 
     OR F_DATE_PRIX IS NULL
RETURN
```

It doesn't seem we can include a MERGE instruction in another MERGE.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.

Source: [link](http://www.exacthelp.com/2012/03/nested-insert-update-delete-or-merge.html)